# When using the Slim Framework the get function is being output as plain text with an error message 'Page Not Found'

Tags: php, routes, slim

I am relatively new to Slim so I am not sure if I am making an obvious mistake. I am trying to build the application in a secure way so the get function is not in the index file. The index requires a file that instantiates the slim app and requires the dependencies, settings, and routes files, the route file then requires the homepage which is where the error comes from.

When the code is run the page output is the get function from the homepage is displayed in plain text and then a error message underneath that reads:

"Page Not Found
The page you are looking for could not be found. Check the address bar to ensure your URL is spelled correctly. If all else fails, you can visit our home page at the link below.

Visit the Home Page"

I am sure php is installed properly as when I try the get function in the index page it run fine, I also tested it with phpinfo().

I am using xampp as my development environment.

```
/**
 * Index.php
 */

ini_set('xdebug.trace_output_name', 'football_trivia_game');
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
ini_set('html_errors', 'On');
ini_set('xdebug.trace_format', 1);

// Include bootstrap
include_once '../includes/bootstrap.php';
```

```
/**
 * Bootstrap.php
 */

// Start the session
session_start();

// Require vendor
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

// Define app path
$app_path = __DIR__ . "/app/";

// Require settings
$settings = require $app_path . 'settings.php';

// Instantiate container
$container = new \Slim\Container($settings);

// Require the dependencies
require $app_path . 'dependencies.php';

// Instantiate app
$app = new \Slim\App($container);

// Require routes
require $app_path . 'routes.php';

// Execute app
$app->run();

session_regenerate_id(true);
```

```
/**
 * Setttings.php
 */
// Display errors
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
ini_set('html_errors', 'On');

// Get app url
$app_url = dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
// Get css path
$css_path = $app_url . '/css/app.css';
// Define css path
define('CSS_PATH', $css_path);

// Set settings
$settings = [
    "settings" => [
        'displayErrorDetails' => true,
        'addContentLengthHeader' => false,
        'mode' => 'development',
        'debug' => true,
        'view' => [
            'template_path' => __DIR__ . '/templates/',
            'twig' => [
                'cache' => false,
                'auto_reload' => true,
            ]],
        'pdo_settings' => [
            'rdbms' => 'mysql',
            'host' => 'localhost',
            'db_name' => 'fbta_db',
            'port' => '3306',
            'user_name' => 'username',
            'user_password' => 'password',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'options' => [
                PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
                PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
                PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => true,

            ]
        ]
    ]
];

return $settings;
```

```
/**
 * Dependencies
 */

$container['view'] = function ($container) {
    $view = new \Slim\Views\Twig(
        $container['settings']['view']['template_path'],
        $container['settings']['view']['twig'],
        [
            'debug' => true // This line should enable debug mode
        ]
    );

    // Instantiate and add Slim specific extension
    $basePath = rtrim(str_ireplace('index.php', ''. $container['request']->getUri()->getBasePath()), '/');
    $view->addExtension(new Slim\Views\TwigExtension($container['router'], $basePath));

    return $view;
};
```

```
/**
 * routes.php
 */

 require 'routes/homepage.php';
```

```
/**
 * Homepage Route
 */

 // Get Request and Response
 use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
 use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response; 

 $app->get('/', function(Request $request, Response $response) {
     $message = 'test';
     $response->getBody()->write($message);
     return $response;
 });
```

I apologise if I have included too much code, I am just unsure where the problem stems from, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is this _every line_ of the homepage file? Did you by any chance forget to include the opening `<?php` tags in this file?

Comment: @Nima No sorry I missed out the php tags but they are there in the files

Answer (score 0):

Slim is very flexible. Your must to specify how you are include the **route.php** script.
My way

**index.php**:

```
declare(strict_types=1);

(require __DIR__ . '/../config/bootstrap.php')->run();
```

**bootstrap.php**

```
declare(strict_types=1);

use DI\ContainerBuilder;
use Slim\App;

require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
(Dotenv\Dotenv::createImmutable(dirname(__DIR__)))->load();

$containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();

// Set up settings
$containerBuilder->addDefinitions(__DIR__.'/container.php');

// Build PHP-DI Container instance
$container = $containerBuilder->build();

// Только для WEB
if ('cli' !== php_sapi_name()) {
    // Create App instance
    $app = $container->get(App::class);
    // Register routes
    (require __DIR__.'/routes.php')($app);
    // Register middleware
    (require __DIR__.'/middleware.php')($app);
} else {
    $app = $container;
}

return $app;
```

In my way **routes.php** is a script wich MUST return a function:

```
return function (App $app) {...}
```

So, in my way, your **routes.php** returns nothing, because **homepage.php** returns nothing

So, in my way, your **homepage.php** muyst be looks like:

```
return function (App $app) {
  $app->get('/', function(Request $request, Response $response) {
     $message = 'test';
     $response->getBody()->write($message);
     return $response;
  });
}
```

So, you must be pass road path from the index.php to route.php in slim. )

Comment: Thank you this had helped, app running fine now with no errors, appreciate the help :)